# How to dynamically render images in react native from file paths

Tags: sqlite, react-native, expo

I am having trouble loading images dynamically in React Native in which the file path is stored in an sqlite database.

Consider 3 buttons:  "Show image1", "Show image2", "Show image3"

I could simply use
`source={require("./assets/image1.png")}`
to load image 1.  I could use a require switch statement on all three images to return the require I need depending on the button pressed.

However, I do not know the paths before the application is loaded. I need to retrieve them from the database and cannot do:

```
var image = imagePathFromDB;
require(image)
```

The offline database pulls user specified images from an online database from which there can be a very large variation of images so specifying all possible paths ahead of time is not possible.

The application is being developed to work for both Android and iOS.

2 Questions:

1. Where is an appropriate place to store the image files
   ..and more importantly
2. How do I retrieve and render them dynamically?

Comment: Your question needs improvement:  1)  Do not ask multiple questions at a time, especially if they are not immediately related.  Storing images is a separate topic from how to retrieve and render them.  Submit another question if necessary.  2) You say "cannot do", but that is not sufficient.  Share error message or other detail about the problem, not just that you cannot do it.  3) The explanation of an offline database pulling images from online database does not make sense.  Provide a better explanation and code to demonstrate what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

in React native ,all your images sources needs to be loaded before compiling your bundle.

you can use dynamic images by using switch case

Like

```
class App extends Component {
  state = { avatar: "" }

  get avatarImage() {
    switch (this.state.avatar) {
      case "car":
        return require('./car.png');
      case "bike":
        return require('./bike.png');
      case "bus":
        return require('./bus.png');
      default:
        return require('./defualt.png');
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <Image source={this.avatarImage} />
  }
}
```

place your images in case and then store only case value for specific output